# How do I run an I/O intensive application only when the computer is idle?

Tags: command-line, monitor, disk, process

Is there a tool which can be instructed to pause specified processes if user uses a keyboard or mouse and to resume it in certain time after user has stopped interaction to the OS?

I would like to treat such way annoying mlocate update db, backuppc.

ps

09.2015 I guess these useful utils bothered me 'cause my Ubuntu was in fact a server, not a desktop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `ionice` utility to set a command's I/O priority to *idle* - this way it won't hog your hard disk when you are working, potentially slowing you down.

The syntax is:

```
ionice -c 3 command-name
```

- `-c 3` sets I/O priority to idle. See `man ionice` for more information.
- Don't forget to prefix `sudo` if the command itself requires *sudo*, e.g. `updatedb`
- You can also use `nice` at the same time to set CPU priority to "idle" too, e.g.

  ```
  sudo nice -19 ionice -c 3 updatedb
  ```

> Note: if the application is run via `cron`, you should also consider changing the scheduled time to when you least use your computer.

Comment: Thank you for that advice! That sounds promising. Going to do some tests.

Comment: Shouldn't nice take 19 instead of -19 ?
sudo nice 19 ionice -c 3 updatedb

Comment: I found that /etc/cron.daily/mlocate runs updatedb.mlocate such way:
/usr/bin/ionice -c3 /usr/bin/updatedb.mlocate.

Is "-c3" proper param? man sais it should be "-c 3"

Comment: no, you need to prefix a `-` to the nice parameter. Only root can assign higher priority, which is...`--20`, say :). Either `-c3 or -c 3` is fine.

Comment: Does this also prevent the disk buffer cache from being filled?